# Get lowest value in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've got a relation OneToMany between my Product and Links. In Links I have a column called `price` I'm passing a list of products to my twig and i want to get the lowest value from `price`. How can I do that?

That's how I'm listing my products now:

```
{% for product in products %}
Name: {{ product.name }}
Price: {% for prodLink in product.getProduktLinks|slice(0, 1) %}
          <span class="price">{{ prodLink.price }}</span>
       {% endfor %}
```

the `slice` allowes me to show only one price but it's not the lowest value. What can I use to make it work?

Comment: You could add a new `getLowestPrice()` method to the Product model as it would require custom logic that cannot be easily accomplished in the Twig context. Use Twig for pure representation only (as far as possible).

Comment: Creating a [Twig Extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) would also work but as @yceruto has pointed out, this functionality probably belongs in the product class.

Comment: @yceruto Any idea how this method should look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

essentially, this is a typical *reduce* operation.

several different ways to do this (however, beware the n+1 query problem):

```
// in the product entity class
public function getMinPrice() {
    return array_reduce($this->getProductLinks(), function($lowest, $link) {
        return min($lowest ?? $link->getPrice(), $link->getPrice());
    });
}
```

you could also do something similar in twig (beware: only in twig >=1.41 or twig >=2.10):

```
product.productLinks|reduce((lowest, link) => min(lowest ?? link.price, link.price))
```

however, it's probably better to adapt your product repository to set the lowest price on a virtual property for example, such that you don't load all links for all products separately...

To be honest, I'm not quite sure if this works

```
// in ProductRepository
public function getWithMinPrices() {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('product');
    $qb
       ->addSelect('(SELECT MIN(pl.price) FROM product.productLinks pl) as minprice')
       // do other query stuff like limiting number of products, searching etc.

    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    // in contrast to normal queries, you now have an array of arrays with
    // one object and the minprice
    return array_map(function($row) {
        $product = $row[0];
        $product->minPrice = $row['minprice'];
        return $product;
    }
}
```

afterwards, you could access that virtual variable in twig via `product.minPrice`

you could also combine the approaches:

```
protected $minPrice = null;
// in the product entity class
public function getMinPrice() {
    if(!is_null($this->minPrice)) {
        $this->minPrice = array_reduce($this->getProductLinks(), function($lowest, $link) {
            return min($lowest ?? $link->getPrice(), $link->getPrice());
        });
    }
    return $this->minPrice;
}
public function setMinPrice($minPrice) {
    $this->minPrice = $minPrice;
}
```

you should then call `$product->setMinPrice($row['minprice'])` in the repository function.

this hybrid approach would ensure, that you always get the minimal price, even if the repository function was not called.

---

as a side note: the reduce calls can always be replaced by a loop:

```
$min = null;
foreach($this->getProductLinks() as $link) {
   $min = min($min ?? $link->getPrice(), $link->getPrice());
}
```

which looks less intimidating and is semantically about the same... something similar is possible in twig, but that's horrifyingly ugly, but might still be good enough

Comment: I used the first method but when I have more than 2 links it compares only two first. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: I've tested this a few times and the reduce call should work, for the twig case as much as the php case. if it doesn't work for you, I suspect that either your `getPrice()` call returns something not easily comparable (like an object) or your `getProductLinks()` calls only returns a subset of prices.

Comment: the first method as a fiddle, obviously the classes are much simplified ... http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/706d97dd9cbde066026bd28be0e4fecda052ee4d twig fiddle for completeness sake: https://twigfiddle.com/51syps